# Enter text in a Read only text field in Robot Framework

Tags: java, automation, robotframework, ui-automation

Using robot framework(with java) I need to pass the file path in a text field to upload the file. However, when i click on the text field it opens the File upload window pop up. In the DOM the field is marked as read only.Below is the screenshot of the DOM for the mentioned element.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfgT3.png)

Is there a way i can enter file path in to the read only text box?

Comment: Please put some robot code snippets to understand the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.